# Dot product between 1D numpy array and scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, dot-product

Say I have Numpy array `p` and a Scipy sparse matrix `q` such that

```
>>> p.shape
(10,)
>>> q.shape
(10,100)
```

I want to do a dot product of p and q. When I try with numpy I get the following:

```
>>> np.dot(p,q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-96-8260c6752ee5>", line 1, in <module>
    np.dot(p,q)
ValueError: Cannot find a common data type.
```

I see in the [Scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html) that

> As of NumPy 1.7, np.dot is not aware of sparse matrices, therefore
>   using it will result on unexpected results or errors. The
>   corresponding dense matrix should be obtained first instead

But that defeats my purpose of using a sparse matrix. Soooo, how am I to do dot products between a sparse matrix and a 1D numpy array (numpy matrix, I am open to either) without losing the sparsity of my matrix?

I am using Numpy 1.8.2 and Scipy 0.15.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `*`:

```
p * q
```

Note that `*` uses matrix-like semantics rather than array-like semantics for sparse matrices, so it computes a matrix product rather than a broadcasted product.

Comment: And be aware of the forthcoming @ for mATtrix multipication https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/

Answer (score 2):

A sparse matrix is not a numpy array or matrix, though most formats use several arrays to store their data.  As a general rule, regular numpy functions aren't aware of sparse matrices, so you should count on using the sparse versions of functions and operators.

By popular demand, the latest `np.dot` is sparse aware, though I don't know the details of how it acts on that.  In 1.18 we have several options.

`user2357112` suggests `p*q`.  With the dense array first, I was a little doubtful, wondering if it would try to use array element by element multiplication (and fail due to broadcasting errors).  But it works.  Sometimes operators like `*` pass control to the 2nd argument.  But just to be sure I tried several alternatives:

```
q.T * p
np.dot(p, q.A)
q.T.dot(p)
```

all give the same dense (100,) array.  Note - this is an array, not a sparse matrix result.

To get a sparse matrix I need to use

```
sparse.csr_matrix(p)*q   # (1,100) shape
```

`q` could be other sparse formats, but for calculations like this it is converted to `csr` or `csc`.  And `.T` operation is cheap because if just requires switching the format from `csr` to `csc`.

It would be good idea to check whether these alternatives work if `p` is a 2d array, e.g. (2,10).

Answer (score 1):

Scipy has inbuilt methods for sparse matrix multiplication.

Example from documentation:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> Q = csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]])
>>> p = np.array([1, 0, -1])
>>> Q.dot(p)
array([ 1, -3, -1], dtype=int64)
```

Check these resources:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.dot.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: This isn't so convenient when q is on the right side of the product.